# Detail field, linked to new report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a main report in Crystal Reports XI that I am using which has fields `ProjectNumber`, `DateOfEvent1`, `DateOfEvent2`, `ProjectCategory`.

I would like to either have an additional detail field OR hyperlink one of the existing fields so that on click it will open a new table with other records specific to that row's `ProjectNumber`.

I've used a parameter field with a subreport but cannot get it to dynamically create reports specific to the clicked row.  I can only create full reports with all the fields (i.e. for ALL `ProjectNumber`).

"Hyperlink to another report object" for an existing field seems like an option, but I can comprehend how that is supposed to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you both.  Won't have a chance to implement until to tomorrow but will be back to clarify or accept based on how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an "on demand" subreport:

- insert a subreport; check "on demand subreport"; click "Report Wizard":

[image]

- click "Link" tab; link main report to subreport:

[image]

- place subreport in desired location; right click and format report; choose "subreport" tab:

[image]

- add a formula for both captions